# Angular: Pipe using Code is adding $ sign on model data

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have two currency pipe example, one using the pipe directly on view and other is using the pipe from ts code side. When I tried to submit the form data, form value related to txtBox2 different and  it is adding $ sign on model data. Is it possible to have same behavior like txtBox1 pipe  on txtBox2 ?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input id="fullName" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="txtBox1" [value]="testForm.get('txtBox1').value | currency">
    <input id="fullName" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="txtBox2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Component code:

```
export class Test1PipeComponent implements OnInit {

  testForm: FormGroup;
  txtBox1Val: number = 1000;
  txtBox2Val: string ;
  constructor(private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe    ) { }
  
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.testForm = new FormGroup({
      txtBox1: new FormControl(),
      txtBox2: new FormControl()
    });

    this.txtBox2Val = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.txtBox1Val, 'USD');

    this.testForm.setValue({
      txtBox1: this.txtBox1Val,
      txtBox2: this.txtBox2Val
    })
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log(this.testForm.value);
  }
}
```

When I run above code I am getting below result:

```
{txtBox1: 1000, txtBox2: "$1,000.00"}
```

I was expecting value on the textBox2 field not to have '$' sign when submitting data. Are we supposed to clean this up before submitting the data?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a reactive form, I think it is better to assign the converted value through form.setValue() or form.patchValue().

On first glance, it seemed to me that the value that you are passing through [value] is getting overwritten by your form.setValue() call, but even when I modify it to form.patchValue() and do not assign a value for the first text box, the value does not get assigned through [value].

What you are trying out with your first textbox would have worked on an independent input field(I have tested) or it might also work in a template-driven form.